# Swift NSAlert() argument print string with spaces

Tags: swift

How do a print the array below to display the full string?

```
alert.informativeText = CommandLine.arguments[4]
```

This prints fine if it's one word. Argument **Test**

```
Test
```

However if the argument is **This Is A Test**. It still prints just the first word:

```
Test
```

Full Code:

```
CommandLine.arguments[1]{
        func dialogOKCancel(title: String) -> Bool
        {
            let alert = NSAlert()
            alert.informativeText = CommandLine.arguments[4]
            alert.alertStyle = NSAlert.Style.warning
            alert.addButton(withTitle: "Dismiss")
            return alert.runModal() == NSApplication.ModalResponse.alertFirstButtonReturn
        }
        _ = dialogOKCancel(title: "")
```

Comment: You'll get an index out of range error for `CommandLine.arguments[4]` if the argument is only "Test". Do you mean `CommandLine.arguments[1]`?

Comment: Yes, sorry it’s [1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space character is the argument separator in the command line.

You have to quote the string

```
/path/to/executable 'This is A Test'
```

or to escape

```
/path/to/executable This\ is\ A\ Test
```

the spaces in the string when calling the executable.

Comment: Thank you. Works fine like this

Answer (score 0):

Command line arguments are always split with spaces. Although "This Is A Test" might look like a single argument, it is four arguments - "This", "Is", "A" and "Test".

What you are trying to do seems to be printing *all* the arguments. In that case, you should drop the first element of `CommandLine.arguments` (that's the command itself) and then `join` the strings:

```
alert.informativeText = CommandLine.arguments.dropFirst().joined(separator: " ")
```